# Kendo UI - JavaScript checkbox value submit to DataSource read

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am a beginner in Kendo Ui and also JavaScript programming. I have a simple question how to submit the value from my checkbox to dataSource transport : read?

so "getMarketData.php" able to get "c1" value (active) and reload in the same page again.

Here I provide my code.

My checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkbox1" class="k-checkbox" checked="checked" value="active" onclick="checkBox()">
```

My Javascript

```
<script>

$(function() {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/getMarketData.php",
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "marketID"
                    }
                }
    });
});

function checkBox() {

    var checkbox = document.getElementById("c1");

    if (checkbox.checked == true) { 
        //pass "active" data
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();     
    } else {    
        if (checkBox.value == 'active') {
            var x = 'inactive';
        }
        //pass "inactive" data
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *transport.read.data* property to pass additional data (more info: [transport.read documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.read#transportreaddata)).

Also, calling *refresh()* is not necessary.

Here's your edited example:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: '/getMarketData.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: function() {
        return {
          c1: document.getElementById('c1').checked,
        };
      },
    },
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: 'marketID',
    },
  },
});
function checkBox() {
  $('#grid')
    .data('kendoGrid')
    .dataSource.read();
}
```